# Can't start Varnish cache on port 80 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu-16.04, varnish

Help me please make friends with my **Ubuntu 16.04 apache2** web-server!

After installing **Varnish cache** started normally. But after **putting it on port 80** varnish can't start:

Creating `/etc/systemd/system/varnish.service.d/customexec.conf`:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s default,256m
```

Then

```
systemctl daemon-reload
service varnish start
```

Varnish do not start:

```
varnish.service - Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/varnish.service.d
           └─customexec.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-07-23 09:41:12 MSK; 21s ago
  Process: 5886 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s default,256m (code=exited, 
 Main PID: 20786 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 23 09:41:12 mj33 systemd[1]: Starting Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator...
Jul 23 09:41:12 mj33 varnishd[5886]: Error: Cannot open -S file (/etc/varnish/secret): No such file or directory
Jul 23 09:41:12 mj33 varnishd[5886]: (-? gives usage)
Jul 23 09:41:12 mj33 systemd[1]: varnish.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=255
Jul 23 09:41:12 mj33 systemd[1]: Failed to start Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator.
Jul 23 09:41:12 mj33 systemd[1]: varnish.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 23 09:41:12 mj33 systemd[1]: varnish.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Tried to create security file and edit `/etc/systemd/system/varnish.service.d/customexec.conf`:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m
```

Varnish started first time, but after stop/start it does not start again:

```
● varnish.service - Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/varnish.service.d
           └─customexec.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-07-24 10:52:41 MSK; 8s ago
  Process: 9974 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/varnishd -a :80 -T localhost:6082 -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -S /etc/varnish/secret -s malloc,256m (code=exited, status=2
 Main PID: 8395 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jul 24 10:52:40 mj33 systemd[1]: Starting Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator...
Jul 24 10:52:41 mj33 varnishd[9974]: Debug: Version: varnish-6.0.6 revision 29a1a8243dbef3d973aec28dc90403188c1dc8e7
Jul 24 10:52:41 mj33 varnishd[9974]: Debug: Platform: Linux,4.4.0-135-generic,x86_64,-junix,-smalloc,-sdefault,-hcritbit
Jul 24 10:52:41 mj33 varnishd[9974]: Empty secret-file "/etc/varnish/secret"
Jul 24 10:52:41 mj33 varnishd[9976]: Version: varnish-6.0.6 revision 29a1a8243dbef3d973aec28dc90403188c1dc8e7
Jul 24 10:52:41 mj33 varnishd[9976]: Platform: Linux,4.4.0-135-generic,x86_64,-junix,-smalloc,-sdefault,-hcritbit
Jul 24 10:52:41 mj33 systemd[1]: varnish.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=255
Jul 24 10:52:41 mj33 systemd[1]: Failed to start Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator.
Jul 24 10:52:41 mj33 systemd[1]: varnish.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 24 10:52:41 mj33 systemd[1]: varnish.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Ive tried to create secret file (/etc/varnish/secret), but nothing changed: 'Jul 23 09:56:31 mj33 systemd[1]: varnish.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=255'
'Jul 23 09:56:31 mj33 systemd[1]: Failed to start Varnish Cache, a high-performance HTTP accelerator.'

Comment: Maybe something else is failing after the creation of `/etc/varnish/secret`. Please add the full output to your original question to see what's going on now.

Comment: Another thing: `default` is not a valid storage type. Please use `malloc` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! Last thing solved my problem

Comment: Unfortunately after restarting the problem repeated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was:

```
Debug: Child (20551) Started
Error: Child (20551) Acceptor start failed:
Listen failed on socket ':80': Address already in use
Debug: Stopping Child
Info: Child (20551) ended
```

Comment: This means you have to set the Apache listening port to `8080` by modifying `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` and by adjusting all your *vhosts* in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.

Then restart both Apache & Varnish, and you should be up and running.

Comment: Thank you very much. My apache configured for ssl. May be you can show me a way, how to configure varnish to cache sites with ssl?

Comment: I can definitely explain how to setup SSL, but I advise you to post this as a separate question. I'll answer it as soon as you post it.